# instantiating a Storyboard as a TabBarItem

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, uitabbar, uistoryboard

I have an old project that has it's view implemented as xibs. The views are controller with a tabbar.

Now I want to add a new UITabBarItem, but I want that this new item is not xib-based, but Storyboard based. Meaning, I want to use a storyboard just for the content of this tabbar item, and leave the rest of the app as it is.

I did the following:

- created the new storyboard
- created a new ViewController that should be the wrapper for the storyboard
- then I changed the underlying VC in IB of the Tab to the new VC

But how to I proceed now? I tried this to make the InitialViewController the ViewCOntroller of the the Tab:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self)
{
    UIStoryboard *financeStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"WS_Finanzierung_Storyboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController * initialViewController = [financeStoryboard instantiateInitialViewController];

    [self presentViewController:initialViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
return self;
}
```

But it doesn't work (crashes yet..).

Q: is that the right way to do it anyway? Is there a best practice doing this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one..

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UIViewController *viewController1 = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *viewController2 = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *viewController3 = [[StoryViewController alloc] init];
    UIStoryboard *tableViewStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard" bundle:nil];
    viewController3 = [tableViewStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"newTab"];
    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[viewController1, viewController2, viewController3];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Assign storyboard identifier like this -->
[image]

and uncheck is initial view controller --> 
[image]

Output ll be like this..

[image][image]